# Custom shaped mask (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, image, mask

I have an array of CGPoints that form a polygon.  I want this polygon to be a "viewing screen" for something else.  This means that whenever something is placed "in" the screen, it is masked by the edges of the polygon.  For example, if I have a square with vertices (-1, -1), (1, -1), (1, 1), and (-1, 1), and I associate that square with this mask, which has vertices (0, 2), (0, 0) and (1, 0), I want the result to be a quadrilateral with vertices (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0) and (0.5, 1).  (Sorry for the verbal description of shapes, but I couldn't make a better example)  How would I go about doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a bunch of stuff with [CGRects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) provided by Apple. Remember that every polygon is really just a union of triangles, and each triangle can be put into its own rectangle. From there, you could write some custom code which looks at which rects intersect, and based on that, if their inner triangles intersect. It's really just matching edges and line intersections. Hope that helps!